# Mockery's andReturn() executing method instead of mocking return value

Tags: php, testing, mocking, phpunit, mockery

I'm Trying to test the following method:

```
/* ConfigurationService.php*/    

public function checkConfigs()
{
    $configurations = $this->getConfigurations();
    return $configurations['configExample'] === '1';
}
```

Considering that the `getConfigurations()` method calls other methods outside this file, inside `ConfigurationRepository.php`,  I've tried to mock only its return and execute the method that I wanna test(`checkConfigs()`): (some code ommited)

```
/* ConfigurationServiceTest.php */       

$configurationRepoMock = \Mockery::mock(ConfigurationRepository::class);
$configurationRepoMock
    ->shouldReceive('getConfigurations')
    ->once()
    ->andReturn(['configExample' => '1']);

$configurationServiceMock = \Mockery::mock(ConfigurationService::class);
$this->app->instance('App\Services\ConfigurationService', $configurationServiceMock);

$configurationServiceInstance = new ConfigurationService($configurationRepoMock);
$response = $configService->checkConfigs();
```

---

The PROBLEM is, instead of returning the mocked result(`['configExample' => '1']`), the method `getConfigurations()` executes, failing due to other method calls inside of it, returning the error:

> Mockery\Exception\BadMethodCallException: Received Mockery_1_App_Repositories_API_ConfigurationRepository::methodInsideGetConfigurations(), but no expectations were specified

Summing up, `andReturn()` is not working. Any ideas?

Comment: `getConfigurations` looks to be part of `ConfigurationService`, not `ConfigurationRepository` which you have mocked. What does that method do?

Comment: It is part of `ConfigurationService`, but it make method calls from `ConfigurationRepository` then returns data based on these methods

Comment: When you replace the instance in the container with this call:
`$this->app->instance('App\Services\ConfigurationService', $configurationServiceMock);` and consequently use the `new` keyword for creating a class you're not replacing anything. You'll have to resolve the instance from the container with `app(ConfigurationService::class)` to get the mocked instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just found the solution...

```
$configurationServiceMock = Mockery::mock(ConfigurationService::class)->makePartial();
$configurationServiceMock
        ->shouldReceive('getConfigurations')
        ->andReturn(['configExample' => '1']);

$response = $configurationServiceMock->checkConfigs();
```

Acording to the docs: http://docs.mockery.io/en/latest/cookbook/big_parent_class.html

In these cases, it's recommended to mock the method return directly, so:

- I added `makePartial()` to the mock call
- Received the mocked result inside the Service Mock itself

Then the `andReturn()` method worked as expected.